# How to loop variable creation automatically?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

When we have to create tk objects with loops it's a relief. But what about times that we want to name them as `var0=first_entry` then `var1=second_entry` etc...? What is the most elegant way to do it?

```
While i < 10:
            self.p{i} = tk.Entry(tk.Frame,
                        width=12).grid(row=2, column=i, pady=10) 
                        # self.p{i} is where i'm stuck
```

Comment: Note to close voters: This question is about creating `tkinter.Entry` widgets, not variables in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you basically want, is nothing else than a dictionary (replace the assigned `i` with your Tkinter expression):

```
d = {}
for i in range(10):
    d["var{0}".format(i)] = i
```

Output:

```
d
{'var0': 0,
 'var1': 1,
 'var2': 2,
 'var3': 3,
 'var4': 4,
 'var5': 5,
 'var6': 6,
 'var7': 7,
 'var8': 8,
 'var9': 9}
```

Comment: Thank you. But how can I access that later? When I want to call it using `keys/items` for binding it to a method e.g. `self.var0.bind(blah blag)` it returns `'_tkinter.tkapp' object has no attribute 'self.var0'`.

Comment: you access it, for example with `d['var0']`. If the dictionary is an instance variable of a class, you access it via `instanceOfClass.d['var0']`.